# SLF4J stops logging to console

Tags: java, glassfish, weblogic, slf4j, logback

I have setup a web application to log messages with SLF4J and logback. I have configured logback to log messages to the console and to a log file but when I deploy the application at some point I stop getting any messages to the console.

I have been trying various configurations with varying results.
With glassfish everything seems to be ok until I run:

```
SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
```

At this point no logs are output to the console.

With weblogic even without installing the  SLF4JBridgeHandler after a redeploy of the application I stop getting log messages to the console (JUL logging still appears in the console). On first deployment  I can also make the console logging fail if I cause a servlet exception  before any other logging happen.

I have tried using log4j2 as the loging implementation as well but the results were the same.

Not sure why console logging is breaking

Using 
SLF4J 1.7.12
logback 1.1.3
glassfish 3.1.2.2
weblogic 12c
here is my configuration:

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true">
<property name="LOG_FILE_NAME" value="compass" />
<timestamp key="byDay" datePattern="yyyyMMdd"/>
<statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />  
<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
    <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
</contextListener>
<jmxConfigurator />
<appender name="compass-con" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%highlight(%-25(%date) %-5level) %cyan(%logger{5}) %msg%n</pattern>            
    </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="compass-async-con" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
    <queueSize>5000</queueSize>
    <appender-ref ref="compass-con"/>        
</appender>
<logger name="com.ciminc" level="DEBUG"/>      
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="org.jboss.seam" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="com.icesoft" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="org.icesoft" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="javax.faces.view.facelets" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="ch.qos" level="DEBUG"/>
<root level="INFO">
    <!--<appender-ref ref="compass-async-file" />-->
    <appender-ref ref="compass-async-con"/>
</root>
```

weblogic.xml:

```
  <container-descriptor>
<prefer-application-packages>
  <package-name>antlr</package-name>
  <package-name>org.apache.log4j</package-name>
  <package-name>org.joda</package-name>
  <package-name>ch.qos.logback</package-name>
  <package-name>org.slf4j</package-name>
  <package-name>org.apache.commons</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
<prefer-application-resources>
  <resource-name>org.slf4j</resource-name>
  <resource-name>ch.qos.logback</resource-name>
  <resource-name>org.apache.commons</resource-name>
</prefer-application-resources>
```